# Replace php form with image or text

Tags: php, html, forms, formatting

I'm trying to make a tic-tac-toe game in school. I've made a 3x3 board with forms like this:

```
<select name=box1>
<option value=" ">&nbsp;</option>
<option value="X">X</option>
</select>
```

and I want it to be replaced with an actual X rather than a select button when it's sent. Is there an easy way to do this? I'm only allowed to use php and html.
A secondary question; right now it's possible to select multiple places to put the 'X''s - is there a way to only allow ONE of the select buttons to show an X at a time?

Comment: can you provide a screenshot?

Comment: This is how my board looks in default: https://gyazo.com/9a17aae2cdc8431b0902c4ac924b5bb2

When I make a move, like this, https://gyazo.com/4f4a0e8607c869bd0690c2620d2f4f60
the information is sent into a .txt file that I created. So when I hit the submit button, the move is registred and saved into the .txt file, like this https://gyazo.com/6880aee7e357a4593b115caf16944e87

However, the middle button is still visible. It obviously shouldn't be possible to place 'X''s twice in the same place - is there a way to remove the middle option when a move is made there?